# Given a function $h(x)$ where we know for $h^{-1}$ to exist, the largest possible domain must be of $x \geq 3$.

Tags: functions

Given a function $h(x)$ where we know for $h^{-1}$ to exist, the largest possible domain must be of $x \geq 3$. Given further that we define the domain of $h^{-1}$ to be $x \geq -2$. Find the set of values of $x$ which satisfies the equation $hh^{-1}(x) = h^{-1}h(x)$.

First, this question seems slightly vague to me (or maybe  my interpretation is bad). For the function $h$ given, we already know $h$ is invertible, and hence $hh^{-1}(x) = x$ is well defined. But isn't $h^{-1}h(x) = x$ too? So aren't they the same function...? So we take $x \geq 3$ as the answer?

Alternatively we can use the theorem that domain of $f \circ g$ = domain of $g$ to do?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "So we take $x \geq 3$ as the answer?.."

Yes, we do.

---

If a function $h:A\to B$ has an inverse $h^{-1}$ then this inverse is unique, has $B$ as domain and has $A$ as codomain.

Further we have $h\circ h^{-1}(b)=b$ for every $b\in B$ and $h^{-1}\circ h(a)=a$ for every $a\in A$

Applying this here we find that we are dealing with functions $h:[3,\infty)\to[-2,\infty)$ and $h^{-1}:[-2,\infty)\to[3,\infty)$.

This with $h\circ h^{-1}(x)=x$ for every $x\geq-2$ and $h^{-1}\circ h(x)=x$ for every $x\geq 3$.

Then: $$h\circ h^{-1}(x)=x=h^{-1}\circ h(x)\text{ for every }x\geq3$$ and for $x<3$ this equality is not true because the RHS is not defined.